# function_score: treat missing field as perfect hit

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

What I need to do is boost documents by location (closer is better). `locations` is nested type.

Works fine **except** Elasticsearch does not return documents if `locations` is missing in document. If fields is missing, Elasticsearch should treat document as perfect hit. Any idea how to achieve this?

My query:

```
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "_score": "desc"
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must_not": [],
               "should": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "locations",
                        "query": {
                           "function_score": {
                              "score_mode": "sum",
                              "functions": [
                                 {
                                    "gauss": {
                                       "locations.coordinates": {
                                          "origin": {
                                             "lat": "50.1078852",
                                             "lon": "15.0385376"
                                          },
                                          "scale": "100km",
                                          "offset": "20km",
                                          "decay": "0.5"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

BTW: I'm using Elasticsearch 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Add one more `function` into the functions section with high boost (like 1000) for missing `locations`, something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "locations"
                }
            }
        },
    },
    "weight": 1000
}
```

So records with missing `locations` will come first because of high weight.

Syntax can differ a little. More information on queries here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: Hmm, I will try. I don't understand one thing: Why does Elasticsearch skip documents without `locations` field? I put my query inside `should` section - not `must`.

Answer (score 0):

use filter inside function

````
POST loc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "title": {
            "query": "McDonald's"
          }
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "location"
            }
          },
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
               "lat" : -23.553720  ,"lon" : -46.652940
              },
              "offset": "200m",
              "scale": "20000km",
              "decay": "0.5"
            }
          },
          "weight": 100
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}```
````